# javascript recursion method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, next.js

I need to do one method linkedIn like that generates automatically a username after registering.

To do so i followed this logic:

1 - get the name and surname and make a join (if name is Tom and surname Hanks then base username would be tomhanks)

2 - I check if that username already exists in the database.

2.1 if it doesn't exist then I return it

2.2 if it exists then I add a suffix and recall the function with the parameter `base username + suffix`

That's it.

I did the following code:

```
    export const buildUsername = async (value) => {
        const { db } = await connectToDatabase(URI, DATABASE);
        let obj = await db.collection(COLLECTION).findOne({username: value});
        if(obj != null) {
            suffix +=1;
            buildUsername(value + suffix)
        }else{
            suffix = 1;
            return value;
        }
    }
```

In the post method I did the following:

```
let username = buildUsername(user.name + user.surname)
//I pretend username to contain a unique username so i could register it into the DB
```

The problem is that this method doesn't work well. if the `username` is unique at the first step then it returns it right. If there need to do some recursions then 'username' is undefined. I have to say that if I log the value before returning it, it seems to work and logs the base username with some numbers after..

What do you think? Is it the right method to do it? Or I just have to think differently?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that the username is not unique, you trigger the `if` branch of your `if-else` statement. In the `if` branch you never return a value, which is why you are getting `undefined` for the username.

Add a return statement before you recursively call the `buildUsername` function and it should work:

```
export const buildUsername = async (value) => {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase(URI, DATABASE);
    let obj = await db.collection(COLLECTION).findOne({username: value});
    if(obj != null) {
        suffix +=1;
        return buildUsername(value + suffix)
    }        
    suffix = 1;
    return value;        
}
```

Comment: this solves one problem but leaves three other issues unaddressed. see my post for details.

Answer (score 0):

JackGore's answer solves the missing `return` problem but leaves several issues in the code -

1. reconnects to the database on each recurrence
2. leaks a global variable `suffix`
3. does not generate usernames sequentially

Here's a way to fix the remaining problems -

```
async function buildUsername (value)
{ const { db } =
    await connectToDatabase(URI, DATABASE) // <- once

  async function loop (suffix)
  { const user =
      await db
        .collection(COLLECTION)
        .findOne({username: value + suffix })

    if (user != null)
      return loop(Number(suffix) + 1) // <- recur
    else
      return value + suffix
  }

  return loop('') // <- initial suffix
}
```

---

This answer will check usernames sequentially, without skipping any values -

```
helloworld
helloworld1
helloworld2
helloworld3
helloworld4
...
helloworld9
helloworld10
helloworld11
helloworld12
```

Whereas your original program will skip many possibilities and results in very long usernames -

```
helloworld
helloworld1
helloworld12
helloworld123
helloworld1234
...
helloworld123456789
helloworld12345678910
helloworld1234567891011
helloworld123456789101112
```

Comment: The question asked about a single problem in the provided piece of code. This answer unnecessarily assumes that the askers wants usernames that follow "1, 2, 3" format vs a "1, 12, 123" format.

Comment: @JackGore: And yours unnecessarily assumes the reverse.  I would bet on Thankyou's assumption ahead of yours.  But note that this answer addresses three distinct problems with the code in the question and your fix to it.  It's overall much cleaner.

Comment: @JackGore _"Sorry but `jack` is taken, would you like `jack1234567891011121314151617181920` instead?"_ Often it is the case that the learner is asking a question for the problem that they see, only to reveal to the teacher that there is another problem (or problems). It is not our role as teachers to follow the learners' questions blindly, but to help them seek questions they didn't know they could ask, and to see problems that are hidden beneath their noses.

Comment: @Thankyou I can see your point about solving additional problems, but at what point do we stop? If we wanted this code to be optimal would we really be looping through all  suffixes to find the next available username? I would argue that we almost certainly wouldn't, so maybe we should refactor your code so that in the case of a very popular username that has the first N suffixes we would not have to do N database reads.

Comment: @JackGore: *At what point do we stop?*  Where you see fit, of course.  Thankyou simply took it a few steps further down what seemed the likely path.  I would actually be very interested in your solution to the problem extension you raise.

Comment: _At what point do we stop?_ i usually don’t speak to code that isn’t presented, but even then there are exceptions like the common XY problem. like when i go to the doctor and say “i think i have coronavirus,” and so the doctor takes the test, measures my vitals, etc. “no, you don’t have coronavirus... but i did notice abnormal heart rhythm and a large mucus build up in your lungs. we should treat that immediately.” doctor’s can’t rely on their patient’s input in order to do their job correctly. every doctor’s treatment philosophy differs but they all do their best to provide complete care.